# i want to use MongoDB with EjabbarD

Tags: php, mongodb, chat, ejabberd

Does anyone know how to use MONGODB with ejabbard.

I want to create a large scale chat system with mongodb and with ejabbard.

Comment: current ejabberd version does not support mongodb . you can use riak or postgresql .

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB is planned to be supported in near releases (along with Cosmos DB). But you are better of using PostgreSQL with BDR replication at the moment.